# C: Program crashes trying to free 2D array itself

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, free

I have a 2D float array contained within a structure `n`:

`float **matrix;`

This is dynamically allocated using:

```
n->matrix = (float**)malloc(n->rows * sizeof(float*));
for (i = 0; i < n->rows; i++) {
    n->matrix[i] = (float*)malloc(n->columns * sizeof(float));
}
```

Where `n->rows` and `n->columns` are defined just beforehand.

When it comes to de-allocation, the following function is used:

```
void de_allocate(float** matrix, int nrows) {
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

The program successfully get through the for-loop within the de-allocation process but gives `HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED [location of error]. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer`.

Note that I am only trying to free the memory for the `n->matrix` not the structure itself.

It makes me think that `n->data` is a different length than what the `free()` method is expecting and trying to write over, but I'm none too sure.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: This is not a 2D array, but only an emulation of it. Such code belongs into the museum. Nowadays, you should have a C99 compatible compiler that is able to allocate a 2D in one go, `float (*matrix)[nrows] = malloc(sizeof(float[ncols][nrows]));` No need for a `for` loop and messing around with several calls to `free`.

Comment: @JensGustedt I've seen this exact same comment on several questions whilst I was searching for a solution, and unfortunately I can't use a C99 compiler for this, painful as it may be.

Comment: The code in the question looks okay to me. Have you tried using valgrind for more accurate debugging?

Comment: You might overflow a buffer somewhere, or pass the wrong number for `nrows`, or any other problem really. To get a good answer, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing when exactly the problem occurs, it could be hard to track down. What you could do is:

1. Run the app via `valgrind` - it will tell you not only that the issue occurred, but also when / how.
2. Make sure the app crashes when it does something weird - `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined` could be helpful.

Comment: The problem occurs when I try to free the array itself (not its elements) due to it trying to write outside of the heap buffer.

Comment: @user3893820 Not exactly. What you see when calling `free()` is the side effect of a problem which occurred much earlier - something wrote over the allocation data of the matrix. To figure out why you're crashing, you need to find where the initial write happened and fix that.

Comment: I see @viraptor. Oddly enough the problem still occurs if I use `calloc()` inside the for-loop to initialise the elements to zero and don't change the values before attempting to free things.

Comment: Ah, running valgrind showed that the error turned up during another function that was altering the structures themselves and messing things up, cheers.